# Manipulating variables in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and I've been struggling to get this to work, basically I would like to know how I manipulate variables in a multidimensional array:

I know I'm supposed to do it in a list, but I have no idea how to

```
// some codes here defining input of week and measurementsperweek

for (int week = 1; week <= 1; week++)
    {
        for (int measurement = 1;
                measurement <= measurementsperweek; measurent++)
            System.out.print(t[week][measurent] + " ");
        System.out.println ();
```

This part shows me the measurements for week 1: so if I had the measurements 5, 45, 67 on that week it will print it out for me. How do I do to manipulate those measurements so I can for instance show the highest/lowest one or just the mean value?

Comment: Your outer loop will loop *exactly* and *always* once (i.e. you could delete it, or more probably it is wrong).  Also, you presumably haven't compiled that code - there are typos.

Comment: Two dimensional arrays are made up of one dimensional array.First you have to iterate over two dimensional array to get the one dimensional array and in iteration when you get the one dimensinal array iterate over it or get or set the value what u want just like

Comment: Also, are you deliberately ignoring the first (zero-th) value in the the nested arrays?  Common, idiomatic looping looks like this: `for(int i = 0; i < measurementsperweek; i++)`.  That is, the first element of an array is at 0, the last as `someArray.length - 1`.  [Also, you'd probably be better off using a list of lists - not arrays.]

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, just call the index position and set it to what you want

```
t[week][measurement] = variable change.
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you are trying to iterate a two dimensional array say t[week][measurement], where week designates the value of the week and measurement refers to the various measurements on that week. For this kind of requirement, i would suggest you to go for a `HashMap<Week_Value,List<Measurement_Value>>` instead of an `two dimensional array`. By keeping the values in a hashmap, you can get the list of measurements of a particular week and get the **highest / lowest / mean** measurement of any week etc

Comment: @Raphel the question is very hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least one other variable, and some logic on the innermost loop.

For the average, for instance, you need to visit each element of the array and add each value, storing the result in another variable.  When you're done, you divide that by the number of values.

For the highest/lowest, you compare each value to the previous highest or lowest value, replacing the highest/lowest value if the new one is higher or lower.  Then, when you're out of the loop, you have the highest or lowest.